# Getting data from JSON Array that has no name from an API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json

I think the app crashes when connecting to the internet.

I'm trying to get the JSON Code and store it in a String variable. I already got the code that extract the definition from it and put it into the TextView.

Comment: How world you suggest we help you?

Comment: Add a proper description of the problem you want us to solve.
[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.